# Replace ( with javascript

Tags: javascript

Firstly sorry for my english

I have javascript statement that doesn't work, can someone tell me how to replace `(` entities?

I use userscript for execute it but it changed to `(_domain.com)` not `_domain.com`

I have tried to search in google but google not read "(" or ")" and i have tried to change `(` with `&lpar;` `&#x00028;` `&#40;` but it cant find it anywhere.

```
document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace("(http://domain.com)","_domain.com");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace all instances, you have to use a regular expression with the `g` modifier; replacing an ordinary string only replaces the first instance. In a regexp, you have to escape special characters.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\(http:\/\/domain\.com\)/g, "_domain.com");
```

BTW, make sure you do this before any other code that processes the DOM (e.g. adding event listeners, setting variables to DOM elements). Since you're replacing the inner HTML of the entire body, it will have to rebuild the DOM from scratch, and any references to old DOM elements will no longer be valid.

Comment: yea .replace use RegExp which is more powerfull